# Compare current time with values in an array true/false

Tags: php, arrays, time

I'd like to define a set of opening hours for a 7 day week. When a visitor visits the web page I'd like to display the current time and day in a specific country (Nevis, Caribbean) and then compare it with a defined set of opening times to show one of two captions 1) Open 2) Closed. Specifically this is what I want to produce:

[image]

I'm using this so far to get the current time and set up the array but how do I compare the two?

```
<?php
    function get_timee($country,$city) {
      $country = str_replace(' ', '', $country);
      $city = str_replace(' ', '', $city);
      $geocode_stats = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$city+$country,&sensor=false");
      $output_deals = json_decode($geocode_stats);
      $latLng = $output_deals->results[0]->geometry->location;
      $lat = $latLng->lat;
      $lng = $latLng->lng;
      $google_time = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=$lat,$lng&timestamp=1331161200&key=xxx");
      $timez = json_decode($google_time);
      $d = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($timez->timeZoneId));
      return  $d->format('H:i');
   }

   $array = array(
      "Monday" => "10:00 - 18:00",
      "Tuesday" => "10:00 - 18:00",
      "Wednesday" => "10:00 - 18:00",
      "Thursday" => "10:00 - 18:00",
      "Friday" => "18:00 - 23:00",
      "Saturday" => "18:00 - 23:00",
      "Sunday" => "Closed"
   );

   ?>
```

Its `<?php echo get_timee("Federation of Saint Kitts and Nevis","Nevis"); ?>`. We're currently ...

Comment: You shouldn't share your API key publicly.

Comment: I removed it, better late than Nevis.. I mean never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this without having to use google anything. I assume you were doing that so that you can work out the time at the clients location. Or maybe because you were not sure what the timezone on your server was set to, or you know it was set to the wrong timezone for you location.

But you can do all this using the core PHP `DateTime()` and `DateTimeZone()` classes like this.

Note: I changed the Opening/Closing times array to make it easier to process!

```
<?php

   $opening_times = array(
      "Monday" =>    array('open' => '10:00', 'close' => '18:00'),
      "Tuesday" =>   array('open' => '10:00', 'close' => '18:00'),
      "Wednesday" => array('open' => '10:00', 'close' => '18:00'),
      "Thursday" =>  array('open' => '10:00', 'close' => '18:00'),
      "Friday" =>    array('open' => '18:00', 'close' => '23:00'),
      "Saturday" =>  array('open' => '18:00', 'close' => '23:00'),
      "Sunday" =>   "Closed"
   );


function AreWeOpen($were_open, $date)
{
    $htm = '';
    if ( ! is_array($were_open[$date->format('l')]) 
        && strtolower($were_open[$date->format('l')]) == 'closed' ) 
    {
        $htm = 'We are closed all day Sunday';
    } else {
        if (   $date->format('H:i') >= $were_open[$date->format('l')]['open']
            && $date->format('H:i') <= $were_open[$date->format('l')]['close']
           )
        {
            $htm = 'We are open';
        } else {
            $htm = 'We are closed';
        }
    }
    return $htm;
}
```

Now to run/test the above all you do is:

```
    // set date time to NOW
    $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo 'Are we open now? Now is ' . $date->format('l H:i') . ' >';
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);

    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open at 09:59 Monday   > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/17 09:59:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);

    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open at 10:00 Monday   > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/17 10:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);

    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open at 18:00 Monday   > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/18 18:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);

    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open at 18:01 Monday   > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/18 18:01:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);

    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open at 18:01 Friday  > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/21 18:01:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);


    echo PHP_EOL;

    echo 'Are we open on SUNDAY   > ';
    $date = new DateTime('2015/08/16 18:01:00', new DateTimeZone('America/St_Kitts'));
    echo AreWeOpen($opening_times, $date);
```

And that gives these results:

```
Are we open now? Now is Monday 07:38 >We are closed
Are we open at 09:59 Monday   > We are closed
Are we open at 10:00 Monday   > We are open
Are we open at 18:00 Monday   > We are open
Are we open at 18:01 Monday   > We are closed
Are we open at 18:01 Friday  > We are open
Are we open on SUNDAY   > We are closed all day Sunday
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the explanation. Yeah I was using Google to get Nevis times but you're solution negates all of that, which is even better.

Answer (score 1):

On outline of a solution:

1. Calculate a numerical version of your opening times array. This array would be a mapping of day of week to opening hours, indexing the days in the same time DateTime->Format('w') would, starting with 0 for Sunday, etc. Each entry could be null for no opening hours, or an array containing the number of seconds into the day at which the store opens.
2. Change get_timee to return the DateTime object iteself.
3. Determine whether the calculated DateTime object falls within the range for the current date. In particular, use (int)$dateTime->format('w') to get the index, then look that up in your numerical array. If the entry is not null, perform the "seconds" calculation for the dateTime item, and determine whether it falls within the range.